# running JQuery through Chrome console: different result

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I am a newbie in JQuery, on a random website, I tried to change the color of a label using the following JQuery selector through Chrome console

```
$('label[for^=URL]').css('color', 'blue' );
```

the result is always

```
[]
```

I installed Tampermonkey, and used the same selector as above on the same page, and surprisingly it works fine,
the script uses

```
// @run-at       document-end
```

so both times the jquery selector is used after the page has loaded so why is it that it does not work through the console and works through Tampermonkey/greasemonkey

Comment: Does the page live inside a frame?

Comment: not the entire page, but the label is within the iframe

Comment: That's your problem then.

Comment: like i said newbie.. so is there anyway to access that label within the iframe through the console?
also i didn't add anything extra to the tampermonkey script, does this mean that the console cannot access the iframe

Comment: You can select the frame first, get its body element, then select from there, but you're getting into quite complicated territory for a newcomer (especially if the pages are served from different domains, which sounds likely here; browsers provide protection by preventing domains talking to each other without mutual consent). Suggest you get started with a simpler page.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('label[for^=URL]').css('color', '#0000FF' );
```

Use color-code instead of the color name